# How to remove mull entries from the Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am very new to javascript and wondering how we can remove the null values from the javascript object without altering the structure of it ?

```
 [
            {
                "name": [
                    "Chris"
                ],
                "data": [
                    [
                        1293733800000,
                        2041.8391
                    ],
                    null,
                    [
                        1301509800000,
                        891.194800000001
                    ],
                    null,
                    [
                        1309372200000,
                        1040.9923
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Mike",
                "data": [
                    null,
                    [
                        1301509800000,
                        4465
                    ],
                    null,
                    [
                        1309372200000,
                        4538
                    ],
                    null,
                    [
                        1317321000000,
                        3700
                    ],
                    null
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
        {
            "name": [
                "Chris"
            ],
            "data": [
                [
                    1293733800000,
                    2041.8391
                ],
                [
                    1301509800000,
                    891.194800000001
                ],
                [
                    1309372200000,
                    1040.9923
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "data": [
                [
                    1301509800000,
                    4465
                ],
                [
                    1309372200000,
                    4538
                ],
                [
                    1317321000000,
                    3700
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have tried this function but it is altering the structure of object with adding index alternatively in each section :-

```
    function removeEmpty(obj) {
        return Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(obj)
            .filter(([_, v]) => v != null)
            .map(([k, v]) => [k, v === Object(v) ? removeEmpty(v) : v])
        );

  }
```

Comment: Is there any reason for the `name` property to be either an array or a string? Otherwise you might just want to map the whole object and re-map `data` only instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": [
      "Chris"
    ],
    "data": [
      [
        1293733800000,
        2041.8391
      ],
      null, [
        1301509800000,
        891.194800000001
      ],
      null, [
        1309372200000,
        1040.9923
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "data": [
      null, [
        1301509800000,
        4465
      ],
      null, [
        1309372200000,
        4538
      ],
      null, [
        1317321000000,
        3700
      ],
      null
    ]
  }
]

const withOutNull = data.map(data => ({
  ...data,
  data: data.data.filter(data => data !== null)
}))

console.dir(withOutNull)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the values of the object and filter only the first level of found arrays.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: ["Chris"], data: [[1293733800000, 2041.8391], null, [1301509800000, 891.194800000001], null, [1309372200000, 1040.9923]] }, { name: "Mike", data: [null, [1301509800000, 4465], null, [1309372200000, 4538], null, [1317321000000, 3700], null] }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, Array.isArray(v)
            ? v.filter(e => e !== null)
            : v
        ])
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original array is called data you can just do

```
const data2 = data.map(x => {
  x.data = x.data.filter(y => y != null)
  return x;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I created the function with input for you:

```js
const input = [
    {"name": ["Chris"],"data": [[1293733800000,2041.8391],null,[1301509800000,891.194800000001],null,[1309372200000,1040.9923]]},{"name": "Mike","data": [null,[1301509800000,4465],null,[1309372200000,4538],null,[1317321000000,3700],null]}]

function removeNulls(input) {
    input.forEach(obj => {
        obj.data = obj.data.filter(arr => (arr !== null))
    })
    return input
}

console.log(removeNulls(input))
```